# How to know users location permission without triggering permission popup?

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, compatibility

I want to use my user's location to do some actions...

The problem is that I don't want to trigger the GeoLocation API popup in case the user hasn't allowed/blocked it, because he'd be confused why I'm asking for it.

So, navigating to `mysite.com/page-that-needs-geolocation`, what should happen is:

1. Redirect the user to another page (`mysite.com/why-enable-geolocation`) in case he hasn't allowed/blocked the GeoLocation, and ask for the permission there.
2. Redirect the user to another page (`mysite.com/enter-your-position`) in case he has blocked the GeoLocation.
3. Let the user continue on the page (`mysite.com/page-that-needs-geolocation`), and use his geolocation.

I'm aware of [Permission API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API), but it's super limited to modern browsers and I can't have that.

Is there a different approach to this problem or another API I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, due to browser limitations.

Canceling (dismissing) or denying permission will lead to the same result, even though you can re-trigger a new permission request in a new session, if the user dismissed the popup.